# Using standard design tokens not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

Attempting to use standard design tokens in my lightning application.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard.htm

have created the defaultTokens.tokens:

```
<aura:tokens extends="force:base">
</aura:tokens>
```

The application TokenTester_App.app

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
   <c:TokenTester_component/>
</aura:application>
```

The Lightning component TokenTester_component.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
  <p>bold text</p>
  not bold text
</aura:component>
```

Finally the component style TokenTester_Component.css

```
.THIS p {
  font-family: token(fontFamily);
  font-weight: token(fontWeightBold);
}
```

When the component is rendered I do not see the text bolded.  What am I missing here??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.THIS p {  should be   p.THIS  {